# Java : I need to make method behave differently for different requests

Tags: java

```
class A 
if(userAuthenticated)
  ArrayList accounts = getAccountForUser(customerId);
UserInfo userinfo = new UserInfo();
userinfo.getUserInfo(accounts);
}

==============

class UserInfo 
{
public ArrayList<String> getUserInfo(ArrayList list) {
ArrayList useraccounts = list;
return useraccounts;
}
}

===============
```

Now inside Class C i will have a String and i need to check , if that String Value exists then do something else do soemthing

The Problem is as this being a WebApplication , i cannot use instance varaibe in the Application .

```
class C 
{

public String makeDBCALL(String account)
{

Here i need to get that ArrayList  of UserInfo  and check if taht  list.contains(account)) 
could anybody please tell me how can do this .
}
}
```

Comment: Must say that your question is a little bit vague. Sometimes is useful to explicit what you have, to know better how to get from that to a working solution. Anyway thanks for trying to isolate the problem :)

Answer (score 0):

**Context**

You need context.

Servlet classes need to be given that context.

**DB or memory**

You could have a reference to a DB (a Datasource) and query every time the DB, or have something in memory (that list by example).

Any way if C is a servlet class that knows it's inside a servlet environment you could ask for the app context. If it's a business class, something more agnostic then it's better to receive by parameter or property the context it needs.

**Setting a context**

If you use Spring configuration (Spring IOC) you could set what the classes needs writing the correct xml.

If you don't, then, at some place you'll need to look for DB connection, or initialize that list and give other classes a reference.

**At last, a concrete solution**

Write a context listener that generates this needed context at initialization (onContextCreated) and hangs it from the application context:

```
class MyListener implements ServletContextListener
{
   contextInitialized(ServletContextEvent event) {
      // Create theObjWEhatYouNeed
      event.getServletContext().setAttribute("whatINeed", theObjWhatYouNeed);
   }
}
```

Configure your web.xml to use MyListener

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>MyListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Then use it from your servlet class (there can be a lot of instances of the same servlet class, have that in mind)

```
doGet(...) {
   MyObj myObj = (MyObj) request.getSession().getServletContext().getAttribute("whatINeed");
}
```

Comment: This is a simple java classes , without J2EE .

Comment: Oops... Then, what means "this being a WebApplication"?

Comment: Mine is a webApplication , but these are simple java classes itself .

Comment: Then provide the needed info without simple classes knowing how to get it (it's bad when your classes *know too much* :). How to provide info? If it's not-depending-on-request info then use setters. If it's depending-on-request info pass arguments.